# Features selection: should I mix features?

Tags: classification, scikit-learn, feature-selection

I have sets of features of different nature(for example, 300 features from FFT-transform, 1000 categorical features and so on). However there are only 900 samples and I`m trying to select important features using Lasso. 
So the question is: should I perform feature selection differentially on subsets of features or better firstly, concatenate features and only then perform feature selection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let LASSO pick the best ones. If the features are highly correlated and you want them picked as a group, add some L2 regularization too. This is called Elastic Net regularization, and it is a generalization of L1 and L2 regularization. Other than that, do not feel obliged to artificially group features.